Плохо ли говорить "здрасте"?
Насколько плохо говорить здрасте?

Спектр мнений
— Если человек говорит "здрасьте", то это можно считать 
неуважением?
— Неуважением посчитаю, если вообще не скажут. А как человек 
это произносит — не важно.
— Здороваясь люди говорят Здравствуйте желая друг другу быть 
здоровыми. А здрасте говорит тупое быдло.
— Окей, буду считать себя быдлом после вашего комментария
— Я считаю, что да. Неуважение чистой воды. Никогда не 
говорю так. Всегда только "здравствуйте". Неужели уж трудно 
сказать нормально. 
— Бесит, когда говоришь " Здравствуйте ", а в ответ 
пренебрежительное " Здрасть", как будто одолжение.


А это статья  Здравствуйте или здрасте? Слова, по которым можно вычислить безграмотного человека

Вот даже так!
Начнём с того, что «здрасте» сказать гораздо проще, чем 
«здравствуйте». Но надо учитывать одно НО! Любые сокращения 
слов в общении с важным для Вас человеком – это неуважение к 
собеседнику.


Пора высказать свое мнение?  Конечно,  не любому человеку можно так сказать, вариант здрасте допускается в определенной ситуации. С другой стороны, слово не то чтобы безграмотно, у него есть своя коннотация. Какая? Думаю, что разная, и это надо чувствовать. То есть словом здрасте можно обозначить дружелюбие или холодность, а также  уважение или неуважение.

ЗДРАСТЕ


Русский орфографический словарь.
здрасте (вместо здравствуйте – при передаче разг. произношения, в поэзии)
Словарь не запрещает?

И вопрос: Какое отношение передает слово здрасте в этом поэтическом тексте Б. Окуджавы:
Арбатского романса знакомое шитье,
К прогулкам в одиночестве пристрастье;
Из чашки запотевшей счастливое питье
И женщины рассеянное ***«здрасте»***...

Не мучьтесь понапрасну: она ко мне добра.
Светло иль грустно — век почти что прожит.
Поверьте, эта дама из моего ребра,
и без меня она уже не может.




Согласен с вами. Но автору статьи самой надо выучить русский язык.

Ну да, согласна, речь у нее несколько "просторечивая". С запятыми не дружит, орфографические ошибки делает.  Так что стилистика и грамотность далеки от совершенства. А тогда и  вопрос  о "колхозе" остается открытым)
